# What is "train" based development?

Tags: agile, development-process, terminology, development-methodologies

I ran across yet another new term in development methodology, and I haven't been able to find a definition for it.  Specifically, it's called "train based development."

Here are some examples of where I have seen this term.

> Earlier this week, I asked our engineering leads and release managers to take the Windows Metro version of Firefox off the trains. (Johnathan Nightingale)

https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2014/03/14/metro/

From the Mozilla careers web-site:

> Experience working with both agile development methodology, and train-based development/QA teams.

I have heard of "train" before and not just in the context of Mozilla.  But I haven't managed to find any good information about it on the net.

When I googled "train based software development", I found very little information in the search results. The closest that I could dig out that separates the train from the wagons is that "train" is about making releases at regular intervals according to a schedule.  But it also seems that "train" is a sort of concrete QA setup.

**So, what is "train based development"?**

Comment: http://scalingsoftwareagilityblog.com/agile-release-train-develop-synchronously-release-whenever/ -- I read Agile Software Requirements from the author and would highly recommend that book AFTER you get yourself familiarized with general Agile ideas and practices.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)**

Comment: @DXM I am quite familiar with agile, mainly scrum and xp, and I have only heard "train" a handful times. Also IIRC "train" is used in context outside of agile, and out of the couple of times I heard it used was before agile came into being, circa 01.

Comment: @gnat I am not dragging anyone into a discussion - I am after a specific and clear definition of a "train" development process/methodology.

Comment: I found tons of useful information here: https://www.google.com/search?q=train-based+software+development

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, although I have to say that there is very little information in that search results. The closest that one can dig out when separates the train from the wagons is that "train" is about making releases at regular intervals according to a schedule. It seems contentious that this maps well to the quote of "pulling Firefox of the trains". It seems that "train" is a sort of concrete QA setup.

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6551/53019

Comment: Isn't this how Ruby on Rails was developed?

Comment: Knowing how well most "development practices" end up going, I read 'train based development' and can't stop thinking about disasters...

Comment: This makes me think of [Microspeak: The train](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/20/10442834.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Summing up information from [this blog](http://thinking-in-code.blogspot.fr/2010/07/train-model-of-software-development.html) :

- The analogy is trains are releases, passengers are features
- Trains are planned at regular intervals, without knowing what they will contain
- If features aren't ready for departure train, they can go on the next one
- Once a version is shipped, the development splits between support/patching shipped code and developing the next train
- This development is mostly aimed at large client softwares, rich in features, and broadly distributed such as a web browser or an OS, where old versions may stay active for a long time.